# How do I open the default mail program with a subject in Python in a cross-platform way?

Tags: python, email

I am trying to add the ability to send mails using the default mail client from my python app.

It can be done with the webbrowser module by opening a 'mailto:' URI.  But, is there a better and direct way to do this like java's Desktop.mail(URI).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my research goes, there is no *proper* solution. We currently use [this](http://translate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/translate/src/trunk/virtaal/virtaal/support/openmailto.py?view=markup) solution, which is the [recipe](http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/Recipe/511443) by Antonio Valentino with a few modifications.

You're interested in the `mailto` function in that file.